# Removed from UK in 2014

Tags: united-kingdom, canada, nigerian-citizens

I am a Nigerian and I went to the UK on a Tier 4 student visa in 2010. I got married to an EU citizen before the expiration of my visa in 2013 but the UKBA established that it was a sham marriage and I was removed from the UK afterwards in 2014 citing violation of my UK visa.

Right now, I am processing my application for Canada PR and I have received my ITA but my concern is would my immigration history affect my chances of getting a PR in Canada?

Many Thanks

Comment: First of all you must tell the truth instead of them finding out. Yes it **can affect** your Canadian PR application. [Reasons you may be inadmissible to Canada](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/inadmissibility/reasons.html). Sham marriages are illegal in Canada and **can** make you inadmissible. We’re you **tried and convicted** in UK? I advice you consult with with a competent Canadian immigration attorney. Note that it is **not automatic&& that you will be denied.

Comment: No I was never tried nor convicted in any court. I was only placed in a detention facility while I appealed my case and subsequently removed afterwards.

Comment: You don't need to be tried and convicted for UKVI to conclude you have a sham marriage. In the visa application, the burden of proof is essentially reversed. That is, you have to prove that you *don't* have a sham marriage rather than the Home Office needing to prove that you *do*. Indeed, I would think that very few participants in alleged sham marriages in the UK would be convicted, since the Home Office's policy is simply to deport them as soon as possible (and preferably before they can get any legal advice).